# Issues after upgrading Hot Towel NuGet Package

Tags: hottowel

I recently ran into a problem upgrading a project I created that was based on the **Hot Towel SPA Visual Studio Template**. I had a "moment" and accidentally ran the `update-package` command in the NuGet Package Manager Console, which triggered an update of ALL my NuGet packages - including the Hot Towel NuGet package.

This had the effect of upgrading my project to the latest Hot Towel version and re-adding all the sample views, view models, etc... that I previously deleted or renamed from the original starter project that Hot Towel created. The NuGet upgrade also failed to refresh files that had I had changed intentionally (`\scripts\_references.js`, `\App_Start\BundleConfig.cs`) or unintentionally (where VS had normalized tab\whitespace in some files I had opened in the IDE).

Has anyone else experienced this?

It seems pretty unlikely you would ever update the Hot Towel NuGet package for any project that takes root and was built off of the template. I could see later in the project lifecycle updating the dependencies like Breeze, Bootstrap, Toastr, etc..., but just not Hot Towel.

Is it best to just unhook NuGet for Hot Towel once you create your project? This would prevent accidental updates of Hot Towel from re-introducing starter code into your project.

Despite this challenge, Hot Towel is proving to be a great starting point for SPAs. I'm really enjoying working with it.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard - that seems like a good plan if you dont want to re-get the entire package. Hot Towel is a convenience and really intended as a starting point. You want to keep up with it a bit though, perhaps in a new project, to see what new versions are brought down together at times. For example, I am getting ready to release an update to Hot Towel soon with some updates to the libraries. In your case you may want to remove HotTowel's NuGet package, but create a new project. Install the new VSIX (when ready) and see what is different in the dependent libraries.

I'll blog this too :)

Comment: Yeah, that's the strategy I was thinking I would take to keep up with what's new in future versions of the Hot Towel template. I figured I'd raise the issue to see if there were other approaches since I'm sure others will hit this eventually too. Thanks for the quick reply and great job on Hot Towel!